# Why function defined in class is not visible in other fragments of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am playing with python, being completely new at that. I wrote my first "serious" piece of code using tkinter and beautifulsoup and stuff and it worked. Now, trying to expand my knowledge I  am re-writing it using pyqt5 and trying to use classes instead of "spaghetti" code. 
My program in general works, it reads website, parses the html code with BeautifulSoup, gets required lines, etc. I used some "calculator" tutorial to base it on and with many trials and errors I made it work. Code below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDate, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import sys
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter

ERROR_MSG = 'ERROR'

class BinColUI(QMainWindow):
    def createLabelTop(self):
        self.label_top = QLabel('PLEASE WAIT')
        self.label_top.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_top.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Bahnschrift; color: yellow")
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.label_top, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def createLabelBot(self):
        self.label_bot = QLabel('PLEASE WAIT')
        self.label_bot.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_bot.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Bahnschrift; color: yellow")
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.label_bot, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def setLabels(self, texttop, textbot):
        self.label_top.setText(texttop)
        self.label_bot.setText(textbot)

    def createLabelImg(self):
        label_img = QLabel()
        label_img.setFixedSize(self.window().width(), 300)
        label_img.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        image = 'img\pleasewait'
        pixmap = QPixmap(resource_path(image+'.png'))
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(label_img.height(), Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        label_img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(label_img, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def setLabelImg(self, bin_color):
        image = 'img\'+bin_color'
        pixmap = QPixmap(resource_path(image + '.png'))
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(self.label_img.height(), Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.label_img.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Bin Collection')
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #7C7D7B')
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.createLabelTop()
        self.createLabelImg()
        self.createLabelBot()

class BinColCtrl:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self.calculateResult()

    def calculateResult(self):
        line_top = parseGoodLines(0)
        line_bottom = parseGoodLines(1)
        self._view.setLabels(line_top, line_bottom)
        self._view.
        '''

        Why the function setLabelImg from class BinColUi is not visible here?
        I can call setLabel (as shown above) but no setLabelImg.

        '''
def parseGoodLines(linia_number):
    global bin_color
    try:
        if linia_number==0:
            start_text='Your next collection is '
        else:
            start_text='After that: '
        kosz_name = good_lines[linia_number][0]
        kosz_date = good_lines[linia_number][1]
        kosz_date_str = QDate.toString(kosz_date, 'dd MMMM yyyy')
        ile_dni=QDate.currentDate().daysTo(kosz_date)
        result = '%s%s\nYou need to put it outside before %s\nIt\'s in %s days' \
                 %(start_text, str.upper(kosz_name), kosz_date_str, str(ile_dni))
    except Exception:
        result = ERROR_MSG
    return result

def resource_path(relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

class MakeSoup:
    def getDataFromWebsite(self):
        URL = 'http://mydurham.durham.gov.uk/article/12690?uprn=100110375827'
        page = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find(id='page_PageContentHolder_template_pnlArticleBody')
        return results

    def mixSoup(self, dane):
        linie_ze_strony = dane.find_all('p')
        global good_lines
        good_lines=[]
        for kosz in linie_ze_strony:
            linia_bez_p = str(kosz).replace('<p>', "")
            linia_bez_p = str(linia_bez_p).replace('</p>', "")
            kosz = linia_bez_p
            if 'Your next ' in str(kosz):
                if 'rubbish' in str(kosz):
                    rubbish_len = len(str(kosz)) - 1
                    date_rubbish = str(kosz)[33:rubbish_len]
                if 'recycling' in str(kosz):
                    recycle_len = len(str(kosz)) - 1
                    date_recycle = str(kosz)[35:recycle_len]
        qdate_rubbish = QDate.fromString(date_rubbish, 'dd MMMM yyyy')
        qdate_recycle = QDate.fromString(date_recycle, 'dd MMMM yyyy')
        good_lines.append(['Rubbish', qdate_rubbish])
        good_lines.append(['Recycling', qdate_recycle])
        good_lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
        return good_lines

    def __init__(self):
        self.mixSoup(self.getDataFromWebsite())

def main():
    bincol = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = BinColUI()
    view.show()
    MakeSoup()
    model = parseGoodLines
    BinColCtrl(model=model, view=view)
    sys.exit(bincol.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In class BinColUi I have some functions which I'm using later on to build and change some visual elements. In class BinColCtrl I change text on the labels using function setLabels form BinColUi class and it works alright. But when I try to call function setLabelImg from the same class it's not visible (see attaached pic) and I can't figure why. In fact only function setLabels is available.

[image]

Comment: Can you please reduce your code down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Your problem depends on one class and one variable, it does not need 140 lines of code.

Comment: Perhaps it's only a problem with your IDE or editor, that it doesn't display all possible alternatives? If you write the function manually and run your script, does it work then?

Comment: Are you sure that the `setLabelImg` method is called on the required object i.e. if you are trying to access it from inside of `BinColUI `, you need to do `self.setLabelImg`

Comment: IDE doesn't know what you will assign to `view` but don't bother this and write code and run it.

Comment: It's already reduced. I'm afraid if I reduce some more I may remove something that's responsible for my problemm but ok, I'll try.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I tried, and it returns error, something like "setLabelImg is not valid attribute of BinColUi" (not exact words).

Comment: You only need a class with two attributes plus an untyped variable to replicate this.

Comment: @furas When I do it, error is:
  File "C:/Python_projects/testy_pyqt5/date_test.py", line 42, in setLabelImg
    pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(self.label_img.height(), Qt.SmoothTransformation)
AttributeError: 'BinColUI' object has no attribute 'label_img'

Comment: And that's an error message you should think about. There is no `label_img` attribute. Where do you think it should come from?

Comment: now you have totally different problem and it has nothing to do with previous problem. You have `label_img` in first class but without `self.` so it is local variable - so you can't access in other functions.

Comment: @Matthias label_img is the QLabel created in createLabelImg, so why it thinks it doesn't exist?

Comment: `label_img` is `QLabel` but it is local variable - you have to use `self.label_img` in all places.

Comment: @furas I used self.label_img, and that problem is gone. But still can't understand what's with annotating variables and stuff. I'm reading about it as Paweł Żukowski said.

Comment: normally python doesn't care what you keep in variable - in the same variable in one moment you can keep integer, in next moment you can keep string or list or dictionary - so Python doesn't know what you will assign to variable so it doesn't know what functions to display in help. Using annotation you define that you will keep only one type of data and then Python know it and it know what functions display in help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IDE does not know the type of `self._view`. It only knows that `self._view` has a `setLabels` attribute because you just used that.

Annotate the variable with the correct type and your IDE can discover the method.

```
class BinColCtrl:
    # ``: BinColUI`` tells the IDE the type of ``view`` and ``self._view``
    def __init__(self, model, view: BinColUI):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self.calculateResult()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your IDE doesn't know type of `self._view` object. It sees `setLabels` because it was used in the line above.

Try adding type annotation like following:

```
class BinColCtrl:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
       self._evaluate = model
       self._view: BinColUi = view  # <-- this type annotation might help
       self.calculateResult()
```

You can find more about type annotations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)